# How to handle failed updates when updating multiple Records in List

Tags: update, rollback

I have a Apex job that runs every night to change a field in multiple records.  I've added some validations to the Object that are preventing some records from being saved.  The problem is even tho one record is failing update, It's causing my whole list of records not to update because I'm using a roll back in the exception.  Is there anyway to remove the failed record from the list and try again? The reason for the failure is in a before trigger i'm throwing an error if some conditions are not met.

```
for (WorkOrder wo : trigger.new) {
    if (wo.AccountId == null) {
         wo.addError('No Account');
    }        
}
```

If I remove the rollback, only records in my list before the one that will fail will be updated, not anything after it? Is that right?

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    try{
        List<WorkOrder> woList = [Select Id,End_Date__c,Status__c from WorkOrder where Status__c = 'Active' and End_Date__c <= :Date.today()];
        for(WorkOrder wo : woList){
            wo.status__c = 'Complete';
        }
        update woList;
    }Catch(Exception e){
        Database.rollback(sp);
        system.debug('-Exception-'+e+'-'+e.getStackTraceString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing normal update you can use Database.update method which has allOrNone parameter which does exactly what you want.

> The optional allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation
>   allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a
>   record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed.
>   This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which
>   records succeeded, which failed, and why. If the parameter is not set
>   or is set true, an exception is thrown if the method is not
>   successful.

```
Database.update(woList, false);
```

This enables the one that don't fail to update as expected.

Salesforce documentation for [Database class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Should I keep my Database.rollback(sp); in the catch?

Comment: No, technically it is not needed because errors are returned to Database.update result in a list type of Database.SaveResult